# Вопрос с выполнением сопрограммы в тг боте

Tags: python, aiogram, asyncio

Есть задача выполнять фоновые задачи, но чтобы бот при этом не блокировался. Как это можно сделать с помощью asyncio вместе с aiogram, для бота. Пытался сделать так, но task `back_work.worker` блокирует основной поток бота.

```
async def main():
    await asyncio.create_task(back_work.worker(bot))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Тут await не нужен и неплохобы таск вынуть из завершенной функции чтоб его gc не скушал:

```
async def main():
    bg = asyncio.create_task(back_work.worker(bot))
    return bg

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bg = asyncio.run(main())
    try:
        executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=False)
    finnaly:
        bg.cancel()
```

Но тут ещё ошибка остается.. перенесите всё в функцию main чтоб экзекутор был в том же лупе что и run.

```
async def main():
    bg = asyncio.create_task(back_work.worker(bot))
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=False)
    await bg

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bg = asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: вылезает ошибка RuntimeError: `This event loop is already running
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Executor._startup_polling' was never awaited
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Executor._shutdown_polling' was never awaited`

Comment: Запусти подругому

Comment: `RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'MainThread.` Пишет